# Radio button: Explain me how to do it

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I'm not a programmer, I try to make some code for hobby. Now I don't want to bother you but for make it simple: I do a roleplay in a site and every character have a "space" for put a code make by html and css like a template. I don't know if you know tumbrl but I find many code by tumbr by searching "roleplay, tabilla, etc". I see most of them use radio button like a link to itself (To go to a to b, etc) but I don't understand how to do it. This is an example I found:

```
<input type="radio" id="cncl-1" name="cncl_group" checked="checked" />
    <input type="radio" id="cncl-2" name="cncl_group" />
    <input type="radio" id="cncl-3" name="cncl_group" />
    <input type="radio" id="cncl-4" name="cncl_group" />
    <input type="radio" id="cncl-5" name="cncl_group" />

    <div class="cncl-tabs">
        <div class="cncl-content">
```

---other code is too long-

```
<div class="cncl-labels">
            <label for="cncl-1">i</label>
            <label for="cncl-2">ii</label>
            <label for="cncl-3">iii</label>
            <label for="cncl-4">vi</label>
            <label for="cncl-5">v</label>
        </div>
```

and css is like:

```
.conciliate input[type="radio"]:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ .cncl-tabs .cncl-content div:nth-child(1),
.conciliate input[type="radio"]:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ .cncl-tabs .cncl-content div:nth-child(2),
.conciliate input[type="radio"]:nth-of-type(3):checked ~ .cncl-tabs .cncl-content div:nth-child(3),
.conciliate input[type="radio"]:nth-of-type(4):checked ~ .cncl-tabs .cncl-content div:nth-child(4),
.conciliate input[type="radio"]:nth-of-type(5):checked ~ .cncl-tabs .cncl-content div:nth-child(5) {
    display: block;
    animation: aparecer 1.5s;
}
```

Comment: Do you speak Spanish? I could help you with that, I just need you to clarify more what exactly do you want

Comment: No i'm italian but i can undertand spanish. This is the link from tumblr:https://www.tumblr.com/alyscodes/699015127164502016/conciliate-pt-aly-corvus?source=share
This girl soo good and i want a "character prifile" like this

Comment: okey its kind of silple, in that case they are not using radiobuttons, they just have their elements with a onclick event, but if you want to use radio you can still using the onclick function

Comment: what you need to do is to set id to your elements and then set theyr display to none and bi the onclick function change the display to block or flex,

Comment: i will make a example and then I send it to you wait me a bit

Comment: Ok i wait you and ty you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the kind of example that I made for you using radio button, but of course you can use any element instead of radio button, like normal buttons or divs, what matters in here is the style and the js function, the style works by hiding the elements and the js to show them by click in the certain elements that sends the id of the area that you want to show, that is not a property for the radio buttons, what radio made is that it just allows you to select just a field from a form and then when you take the value of each radio you will have one true from the element that was selected

```js
    function changepage(id) {
        clean();
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
    }

    function clean() {
        let z1 = document.getElementById('zone1');
        let z2 = document.getElementById('zone2');
        let z3 = document.getElementById('zone3');
        z1.style.display = 'none';
        z2.style.display = 'none';
        z3.style.display = 'none';
    }
```

```css
    .cont {
        height: 60px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: #cad2ff;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .rowCont {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 23px;
        background-color: #f0f0f0;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    input {
        margin-right: 10px;
        height: 49px;
    }
    
    #zone1,
    #zone2,
    #zone3 {
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="cont">

        <div id="zone1">
            a
        </div>
        <div id="zone2">
            b
        </div>
        <div id="zone3">
            c
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="rowCont">
        <label for="1">page 1</label>
        <input onclick="changepage('zone1')" id="1" type="radio" name="page">
        <label for="2">page 2</label>
        <input onclick="changepage('zone2')" id="2" type="radio" name="page">
        <label for="3">page 3</label>
        <input onclick="changepage('zone3')" id="3" type="radio" name="page">
    </div>
```

Comment: Hope this works for what you were looking for

Comment: Finnaly i undertand how to do it! ty for yout help ❤️